# Passing different types of parameters to a function template

Tags: c++, function, templates

Consider this template:

```
template<typename t>
t add(t a, t b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

How can I pass different types of parameters so the return value will be:

- `int` if both parameters are of type `int`.
- `float` if one of the parameters is of type `float`.
- `float` if both parameters are of type `float`.

I've also tried having multiple parameters for the template:

```
template<typename t, typename c>
```

using them for the function parameters so they can be different (`t add(t a, c b)`) but what I can't wrap my head around is how can I change the type of function (int, float, double, etc.) depending on the return type?

Comment: Note that template parameters are usually uppercase by convention.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want is [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type):

```
template<typename T0, typename T1>
typename std::common_type<T0, T1>::type add(T0 a, T1 b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

The documentation states:

> For arithmetic types, the common type may be viewed as the type of the (possibly mixed-mode) arithmetic expression such as T0() + T1() + ... + Tn().

But, as pointed by @Jarod42 in the comments, this is just a view, and may be wrong in some cases: for example, `std::common_type<char, char>::type` is `char` whereas the arithmetic expression `char() + char()` yields `int`.

---

A more complete implementation may explicitly cast the result to remove possible warnings in the cases cited above:

```
template<typename T0, typename T1, typename R = std::common_type_t<T0, T1>>
R add(T0 a, T1 b) {
    return static_cast<R>(a+b);
}
```

Here `std::common_type` is used by default for return type, but since it is a template parameter, you may specify a different type when using the function (may be useful in more complex use cases):

```
char a = 1, b = 2;
add<decltype(a), decltype(b), int>(a, b);
```

---

Using [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) and [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same), an even more complete solution proposed by @Jarod42 in the comments allows to have template `R` as first parameter, and keep automatic deduction for `a` and `b`:

```
template <typename R, typename T0, typename T1>
using ResType = std::conditional_t<
    std::is_same<void, R>::value,
    std::common_type_t<T0, T1>, // default
    R                           // R was explicitly specified: use it
>;

template <typename R = void, typename T0, typename T1>
ResType<R, T0, T1> add(T0 a, T1 b)
{
    return static_cast<ResType<R, T0, T1>>(a + b);
}
```

Usage:

```
char a = 1, b = 2;
add(a, b);       // returns char
add<int>(a, b);  // returns int
```

Comment: The note is misleading, as `std::common_type_t<char, char>` is `char` whereas `decltype('c' + 'c')` is `int`.

Comment: You may even do something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21fc2b311675215f) to have template `R` as first parameter and allow deduction of `T1`, `T2`.

Comment: @Jarod42 thx, I was searching how to do it. I edited my answer

Comment: Using traits is another possible solution that doesn't require the extra parameter (it requires extra classes anyway).

Answer (score 11):

Use [auto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) type deduction (since c++14):

```
template<typename t, typename u>
    auto add(t a, u b) {
        return a+b;
    }
```

Comment: Note that `char + char` result in `int`, whereas other answers result in `char`.

Comment: A modification of this for C++11 would be to change `auto add(t a, t b)` to `auto add(t a, t b) -> decltype(a+b)`.

Comment: If the behaviour that @Jarod42 mentioned is undesirable, you can provide a specialisation `template<> auto add<char, char>(char a, char b) { return static_cast<char>(a + b); }` (with or without the `<char, char>`, since `t` and `u` can be deduced from the parameter list).  Note that this could potentially cause loss of data, however.

Answer (score 6):

In c++11 and onward, you can use [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type)

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto add(T1 a, T2 b) -> typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type {
  return a + b;
}
```

It will work as if integral promotions are happening, not much different than just doing `auto` type deduction, as in [Piotr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41320283/817643)'s answer. But it will really start to shine if you try to pass custom types as parameters, such as `std::complex` classes.

---

I'd prefer to preserve the integral promotion types that the standard imposes, so perhaps this should be wrapped in another trait.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class AdditionTraits {
  using common_t = typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type;
  constexpr static bool is_char = std::is_same<common_t, char>::value;
public:
  using type = typename std::conditional<is_char, int, common_t>::type;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto add(T1 a, T2 b) -> typename AdditionTraits <T1, T2>::type {
  return a + b;
}
```

You [can see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae5c484fe4726399) it adds `char`s into an `int`, as the standard promotion rules do.

Comment: Note that `char + char` result in `int` for PiotrNycz's answer, whereas your result in `char`.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Interesting. Won't that cause a warning to be emitted when my template is used? The addition still results in an `int`. But the return type is `char`.

Comment: I think some compilers have special flag to detect implicit convertion or possible loss of data.

Comment: @Jarod42 - they do. I just don't think it's a good idea to turn those off. And if this code can quite often result in one, perhaps there's room for improvement...

Comment: The way to remove warning would be `return static_cast<std::common_type_t<T1, T2>>(a+b);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 - I prefer to go with the compiler instead of silencing it with a cast, added my musings as an edit.

Comment: What is valid for `char` is also valid for other types as `signed char`, `short int`, `uint8_t`, ... (integral types that are smaller than `int`), So you may play with `std::is_integral` and `sizeof`.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Yes, Addition traits is far from complete. Maybe I'll tinker with it later. As it is now, it expresses my concern and approach, which is good enough for me.